# Can´t consume Json from MVC and Web API controller

Tags: json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to consume json data from a web API in .NET.  I tried by two ways, with web API and returning Json with a MVC controller but I can't consume from any of both. I only can consume it from a view inside my project, but when I try to consume with a html page outside my project it throws an error.[image]

It is hosted in azure. Here is the code of the Action.

```
public ActionResult PreguntasById(int id)
    {
        var emp = db.pregunta_area.Where(i => i.fk_pregunta == id).Select(e => new
        {
            id = e.fk_pregunta,
            pregunta = e.Preguntas.pregunta,
            area = e.fk_area
        }
        ).ToList();

        return Json(emp, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet );
    }
```

And my AJAX petition.

```
function siguientePregunta()
{
    $("#pregunta").remove();

            $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'http://carrierintegrator.azurewebsites.net/Preguntas/PreguntasById/'+contador,
        async: true,
        success: function (response) {
            $("#pregunta-content").append("<h6 id='pregunta'>"+response[0].pregunta+"</h6>");
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function (obj, error, objError) {
            alert("Error interno: " + objError);
            console.log(id_pas);
        }
    });
            contador++;
}
```

Also I tried to quit the dataType but it's useless. I don't know what it's going wrong.

I'm doign the same in the Web API Controller but i'm having the same error.

Comment: Have you checked the HTTP request to make sure the URL and response are what they should be? All major browsers have a way to view the raw HTTP request and response in their developer tools. I'm guessing there is something wrong with the request which is making the server return an error page instead of JSON.

Comment: Thank you, I noticed that i was getting an error because i had not CORS enabled in my API so I enabled it and now It is solved.